# Bootstrap Modal with button type="submit"

Tags: button, types, modal-dialog, submit

```
<button type='submit'
        value='".$complainListArray['CompID']."'
        class='btn btn-default' 
        style='width:95px;float:right' 
        data-toggle='modal' 
        data-target='#myModal'
        name='button_update_sentiment'
        id='button_update_sentiment'
        >Update</button>
```

I got this problem, when type='submit', then the Bootstrap Modal is not showing.
It works when I use type='button', but then I can't carry the value of the button.
Need help. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want to toggle Modal but why button type is submit?

Comment: I'm using a loop to generate dynamic buttons. So i need to assign different value to each button. When it toggle the Modal, so i know which button is triggering it.